# EMMC with unblanced block erase count

Tags: linux, boot, io, embedded-linux

We developed some embedded Linux products which write data log 24h*7 to 8GB eMMC chips. When reading the block erase counts of every block inside the eMMC chips by sending the CMD56 command. We found the erase counts distributed not balance. For example, from block number 50-83, it is about 6000 times each block. Other blocks are about 500 times for each block.

[image]

[image].

According to my knowledge, the eMMC has FTL(Flash Translation Layer) and Wear Levelling function are inside its own firmware. So, the erase counts should be somehow equal to an average number no matter how many are the partition numbers and how large is each file system. Am I right here? Now we have 3 partitions:  P1:250MB(rootfs), P2:250MB(backup rootfs), P3:6.7GB(data). If my understanding is wrong. How can we improve the eMMC write levelling(increase eMMC's lifetime)? Thanks.

Comment: How full is the drive? Could you be seeing the highest writes to the only remaining free space?

Comment: I don't think that every eMMC system has built-in FTL. The block erase numbers do not look like there is an FTL active as long as the eMMC has enough free disk space.

Comment: *"According to my knowledge, the eMMC has FTL(Flash Translation Layer) and Wear Levelling function ..."* -- True, but there are degrees of wear-leveling capability, and low-cost FTL devices such as SD cards and eMMC do not have the same wear-leveling capabilities as SSD.  Perhaps you need to track the heath of an eMMC from first use to understand the limits of its wear-leveling.

Comment: Thanks for all of you guys. I just got a reply from the FAE of our eMMC supplier. They said "This is due to system blocks in pSLC mode and regular blocks in MLC mode. The system blocks have 10X the endurance. The user area is MLC which has an endurance of 3,000 cycles. The system area has an endurance of 30,000 cycles. Our wear-leveling algorithms have been tested and are well proven."

Answer (score 1):

Writes may well be redistributed across the entire device but there are caveats.

1. Blocks that are TRIM'ed by your operating system are actively considered "free" and available to be rewritten. Those blocks will simply be erased during time when the device is idle and returned to the pool of blocks available for use.
2. Assuming TRIM is enabled, blocks that are written are unlikely to be actively read and rewritten elsewhere. If you have a lot of very rarely written data, such as your operating system partitions, then those blocks are likely to have far lower writes.
3. If TRIM is disabled then the device will have to figure out least recently used blocks, read the data, write it elsewhere, then erase the block. This will have a significant performance penalty compared to a known empty block.

With TRIM enabled I would still expect to see some areas which show lower writes.

It is possible that your filesystem has TRIM enabled *for newly deleted data* but is not reporting the full filesystem empty blocks for the device, resulting in a small area being excessively written as data gets written, deleted, the blocks reliably TRIM'ed and then reused.

Apparently

```
sudo fstrim -v /
```

might help.  Replace `/` with your mount point for the data partition. If it comes back with a significant area TRIM'ed then it might be a benefit to run occasionally. I believe Windows TRIMs empty space on a weekly or monthly basis.

Command from [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/729279/large-amount-of-data-trimmed-after-running-fstrim)

Comment: You are overly focused on TRIM.  As you mention in #2, TRIM does nothing for wear-leveling of blocks already in-use.  IOW you are overlooking the need for garbage collection, a (background) process which would relocate data from low-erase-count blocks.  OP should report the eMMC version of his module and/or determine if a `force garbage collection` command is available.